# How do pointers work in a linked list (Java)

Tags: java, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

```
/**
 * Definition for polynomial singly-linked list.
 * class PolyNode {
 *     int coefficient, power;
 *     PolyNode next = null;
 
 *     PolyNode() {}
 *     PolyNode(int x, int y) { this.coefficient = x; this.power = y; }
 *     PolyNode(int x, int y, PolyNode next) { this.coefficient = x; this.power = y; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
```

```
       PolyNode iter1 = poly1;
       PolyNode poly1 = null;
       while(iter1 != null){
           PolyNode next = iter1.next;
           iter1.next = poly1;
           poly1 = iter1;
           iter1 = next;
       }
```

I'm very confused on the above while loop. I couldn't tell how this while loop would do to the linkedlist poly1. Please help me out!

Inside the while loop, the 1st line create a copy of the 'iter1.next'.
the 2nd line makes the 'iter1' points to the 'poly1'.
the 3rd line let 'poly1' become 'iter1'.
the 4th line let iter1 become the 'next'.

Please correct where I got wrong, as I tried to draw the graph from the above logic. and it didn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Did the answer help to clear the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't copy anything, it assigns the reference. All statements are executed in order. The assignment operator assigns the value of the right-hand side to the variable on the left-hand side. (It's not an equivalence relation as in mathemetics).

1. `PolyNode next = iter1.next;` stores a *reference* to the next node of the current node into variable `next`.
2. `iter1.next = poly1;` updates the reference to the next node of the current node to reference the same object instance that reference `poly1` currently does. Note that `poly1` starts with `null` as value.
3. `poly1 = iter1;` updates the `poly1` reference to reference the same object instance as the `iter1` reference.
4. `iter1 = next;` updates the `iter1` reference to reference the same object instance as the `next` reference (the old `iter1.next` reference, before it got changed to `poly1`).

I'll try to draw the steps as beautiful ASCII art:

We'll start with a simple linked list with 3 nodes (i.e. `A.next == B; B.next == C; C.next == null;`). We start with `iter1` referencing the first node and `poly1` referencing "nothing" (i.e. `null`):

```
A->B->C->null
^------------ iter1
         ^--- poly1 (of course, this there isn't any single null)
```

1. `PolyNode next = iter1.next;`

   ```
   A->B->C->null
   ^------------ iter1
      ^--------- next == iter1.next
   ```
2. `iter1.next = poly1;`

   ```
   A->null | B->C->null
   ^------------------- iter1
      ^---------------- iter1.next == poly1 (== null)
             ^--------- next
   ```
3. `poly1 = iter1;`

   ```
   A->null | B->C->null
   ^------------------- iter1 == poly1
      ^---------------- iter1.next == poly1 (== null)
             ^--------- next
   ```
4. `iter1 = next;`

   ```
   A->null | B->C->null
   ^------------------- poly1
             ^--------- next == iter1
                ^------ iter1.next
   ```

Next iteration of the while loop (`iter1 != null`):

1. `PolyNode next = iter1.next;`

   ```
   A->null | B->C->null
   ^------------------- poly1
             ^--------- iter1
                ^------ iter1.next == next
   ```
2. `iter1.next = poly1;`

   ```
   B->A->null | C->null
   ^------------------- iter1
      ^---------------- poly1 == iter1.next
                ^------ next
   ```
3. `poly1 = iter1;`

   ```
   B->A->null | C->null
   ^------------------- iter1 == poly1
      ^---------------- iter1.next
                ^------ next
   ```
4. `iter1 = next;`

   ```
   B->A->null | C->null
   ^------------------- poly1
                ^------ next == iter1
   ```

Next iteration of the while loop (`iter1 != null`):

1. `PolyNode next = iter1.next;`

   ```
   B->A->null | C->null
   ^------------------- poly1
                ^------ iter1
                   ^--- iter1.next == next
   ```
2. `iter1.next = poly1;`

   ```
   C->B->A->null
   ^------------ iter1
      ^--------- poly1 == iter1.next
            ^--- next
   ```
3. `poly1 = iter1;`

   ```
   C->B->A->null
   ^------------ iter1 == poly1
      ^--------- iter1.next
            ^--- next
   ```
4. `iter1 = next;`

   ```
   C->B->A->null
   ^------------ poly1
            ^--- next == iter1
   ```

`iter1 != null` is now false and the loop terminates. Your function effectively reverses the linked list by prepending all nodes to a new list; I hope its name is `reverse()`.